# Shapiro-Francia test error

Tags: r, sample-size, normality-assumption, lme4-nlme, residuals

I'm trying to run a normality test on the residuals after fitting a mixed-effect model (with lmer).  I read that the Shapiro-Francia test can deal with data with more than 5000 observations (I have more than 8000), but when I run it I get an error:

```
sf.test(resid(dat.lmer11))
```

Error in sf.test(resid(dat.lmer11)) : 
  sample size must be between 5 and 5000

Could anyone help, please?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, isn't it? The test itself may work for any sample size, but the sf.test function doesn't. Also, tests of normality are of little use. With such a large sample size, the null hypothesis is almost certain to be rejected if it's real data (as opposed to simulated data).

Comment: Are there missing data in your analysis dataset? You may have greater than 8000 rows counting rows with missing values. The mixed model drops those rows for a complete case analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just edit the `sf.test()` to allow for the big vector

```
sf.testBIG=function (x) 

    {
    DNAME <- deparse(substitute(x))
    x <- sort(x[complete.cases(x)])
    n <- length(x)
    if ((n < 5 || n > 10000))   ###            <-----here is my edit
        stop("sample size must be between 5 and 10,000")
    y <- qnorm(ppoints(n, a = 3/8))
    W <- cor(x, y)^2
    u <- log(n)
    v <- log(u)
    mu <- -1.2725 + 1.0521 * (v - u)
    sig <- 1.0308 - 0.26758 * (v + 2/u)
    z <- (log(1 - W) - mu)/sig
    pval <- pnorm(z, lower.tail = FALSE)
    RVAL <- list(statistic = c(W = W), p.value = pval, method = 
       "Shapiro-Francia normality test", 
        data.name = DNAME)
    class(RVAL) <- "htest"
    return(RVAL)
}
```

Then run your test on data that is bigger than the package creator intends.

```
sf.testBig(resid(dat.lmer11))
```

Also, bear in mind that the normality test's null and alternative hypothesis are usually backwards for most uses. Ie. Sometimes you can claim you have evidence for non-normality, but you can never have evidence for normality.